# angular-google-charts how to add legends for Bar Chart?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chat

I'm trying to convert my current Google Chart written in ReactJS to the new Angular 10 web app. I've found this [angular-google-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-charts) which seem to be the Angular version of the React's [react-google-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-charts).

Unfortunately, the Angular library is lacking in the documentation department. I was able to piece a partial working chart from Google search and was able to replicate the same result as the existing chart, but I cannot figure out as to how I can set legends, at the moment they are empty.

Here's the current code I have:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartType } from 'angular-google-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

  chartType = ChartType.Bar;
  chartOptions = {
    colors: ['#216f31', '#a00909'],
    legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
  };
  columns: ['Income', 'Expenses', ];

  chartData = [
    // ['Month', 'Income', 'Expenses'],
    ['Apr', 1398.36, 0],
    ['May', 3255.20, 2704.15],
    ['Jun', 390, 3348.40],
    ['Jul', 1300.00, 0],
    ['Aug', 382.50, 0],
  ];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```html
<fieldset class="position-relative ml-2">
  <legend class="display-4 mb-0">Chart</legend>
  <google-chart style="width: 90%; height: 80%;"
            [type]="chartType"
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [columns]="columns"
            [data]="chartData"></google-chart>
</fieldset>
```

> #### This what it produces

[image: Angular]

> #### This what the React version looks like

[image: ReactJS]

Does anyone have any idea how I can get the two legends on the right to populate as it has on the React one?

*ps: the commented-out line in the `chartData` array is all it takes to produce the legends in React, but that doesn't work on Angular*

Any help is much appreciated.

*In case anyone's wondering I've also tried the [ng2-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts) as well but it's more complex than what I need and I'd like to leave that as a last resource since I've to transform my data structure to a much more complicated one for that to work.*

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I've defined the type of variable the `columns` is:

```
columns: ['Income', 'Expenses', ];
```

Instead, I was supposed to initialise it:

```
columns = ['Month', 'Income', 'Expenses', ];
```